# How to get unique count without distinct

Tags: postgresql

I must count a number of unique surnames and names in the Postgresql table.
The problem is usage of distinct is denied by task.

What I tried to do:

```
SELECT COUNT(SURNAME), COUNT (NAME) FROM PEOPLE GROUP BY NAME, SURNAME;
```

Output:

> 1 1 1 1 1 and etc
>   (4939 rows)

But it looks like I did something wrong because in output I must get only two digits with a count.
Any idea what to do with it?

Comment: Please show us sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get around using `DISTINCT` by first grouping by the name or surname, and then taking a count of that intermediate table.

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
        (SELECT SURNAME FROM PEOPLE GROUP BY SURNAME) t) AS surname_cnt,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
        (SELECT NAME FROM PEOPLE GROUP BY NAME) t) AS name_cnt
```